# Angular - How to avoid initial load animation with query

Tags: angular, animation, triggers

I'm using Angular 10 (but the question should be the same for Angular 2+)

I have a specific page which need `query('.xxx')` to animate multiple DOM elements on page load / unload.

I want to applies these animations on page load / unload, UNLESS if this is the first load (first page view when the user come on the site).

I tried so many things:

- animations on the parent view
- animations on the child view
- animation on the child view with specific states (doesn't work because page transition are executed before state change)
- use the special `:enter` to disable animation on first load

I can get it with specific page change triggers, like `home => pageA`, `xxx => pageA`, but I don't want to list all possibilities... The idea is to get it work with `* <=> *`  or at least `* => pageA` :)

Nothing gets the expected result... It's a common case I think, could someone help me to achieve that ?

I did a stackblitz to show the idea: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-avoid-first?file=src/app/page-a.component.ts

The switch home <=> pageA should trigger the animations, but the initial load on pageA shouldn't...

Here I post the simple example code:

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { animate, animateChild, query, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<main [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
              <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
            </main>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimations', [
      transition(':enter', []), // to try disabling first animation
      transition('* <=> *', [
        query(':leave', animateChild(), { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', animateChild(), { optional: true }),
      ]),
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  }
}
```

***home.component.ts***

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `<h1>THIS IS HOME</h1><a [routerLink]="['/']">Page A</a>`,
  styles: []
})
export class HomeComponent  {
}
```

***page-a.component.ts***

```
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { animate, stagger, style, transition, query, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-a',
  template: '<div class="red">ELEMENT</div><button (click)="changePage()">Change Page</button>',
  styles: ['div {width: 200px;height: 100px;background: #f00}'],
  animations: [
    trigger('animation', [
      transition(':enter', [
        query('.red', [
          style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-100px)'}),
          animate('500ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'none' }))
        ])
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        query('.red', [
          animate('500ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)', style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-100px)' }))
        ])
      ])
    ]),
  ]
})
export class PageAComponent {
  
  @HostBinding('@animation')
  public animation;

  public constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public changePage(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: I think you could investigate animation builder which would refer to page-wide service which contains info whether it's a first load and build an appropriate animation

Comment: why not just use a cookie, and read it from JS.  Could use server-side and a session as well.  Presuming you can use HTML5 you could use local storage as well.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to make it with simple animation api. what I can propose to you is detect which order of navigation is happening right now and disable all animations if it is the first one. 
Component:

```
routeLoadNumber$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd),
    scan((a)=> a + 1, 0)
  );

constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

html

```
<main [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)" [@.disabled]="(routeLoadNumber$ | async)==1">
```

Comment: I'll try on the stackblitz ; can you explain to me why the "no-op" (aka. empty :enter) doesn't disable child animation ? It's routing void => page, that's the animation I want to disable

Comment: you can remove the whole "routing" animation, and your :enter animation inside of the component will yet be run. it is not related

Comment: I thought it was related because on the official documentation, it's said that parent animation take the lead on children components animation ; so disable :enter from parent should disable :enter from child